# C# Serialization and properties

Tags: c#, serialization, properties, xml-serialization

I have a kind of foreignkey implementation, so that my class has a field that is a reference to another object, and then it has a property that fetches the other object on demand:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass {
    private string otherId;
    public SomeClass Other {
        get { return SomeClass.GetById(otherId); }
        set { otherId = value.id; }
    }
}
```

Now, can anyone please explain what happens when I serialize/deserialize this class using C# default serialization (I'd like to understand both binary and XML serialization please)

Comment: I'm trying to understand what happens behind the scenes, not just the end result. My real scenario is much more complicated, this is a simplified example.

Comment: The simple answer is that the serializer, regardless of the target format, is going to call your getter and then serialize the Other proerty as SomeClass.  Whether that is going to throw an exception or not depends on what omeClass.GetById actually does.

Comment: I see, so basically it's going to redundantly serialize the same variable twice. BTW, I did try it, and although SomeClass is not defined as Serializable, it works fine. Any explanation?

Comment: Its implied as serializable since it is a property of a serializable object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that the serializer, regardless of the target format, is going to call your getter and then serialize the `Other` property as `SomeClass`. Whether that is going to throw an exception or not depends on what `SomeClass.GetById` actually does.

`SomeClass` is implied as serializable because it is a property of a serializable object.

Comment: Thanks. So I understand that serializing will call the getter, serialize the result, and then when deserializing, will call the setter with that serialized value. In my case, the private string will be overwritten with the same value twice (the id).

Comment: Hmm... when I made Other a regular field of type SomeClass instead of a property, it threw an exception saying SomeClass is not marked as serializable...

Answer (score 2):

Both otherId and Other members will be serialized/deserialized.

To stop Other property from being serialized, you can use `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute on that property.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use this for the property and then only the field will be serialized.